# Проверка строки через регулярные выражение на наличие определенного слова

Tags: php

помогите как новичку пхп, регулярные выражения не мой конек, соответственно задача такая.
Допустим в переменной $group будут хранится названия групп, они могут быть как числовые так и строковые, и так же смешаны. то есть значения могут быть "club5353" или "234534" или "superlife" моя задача сделать проверку и отловить все названия которые имеют в себе слово club и после цифры, то есть эти "club5353" затем с этого название надо убрать слово club и оставить только цифры.
В итоге, мне надо сделать проверку которая будет проверять то что в переменой и если там будет "club123456" надо обрезать клуб, и оставить только цифры.
За ранние спасибо! С меня плюс в карму!

Comment: Почему именно регулярки? Берете `strpos` если данное слово найдено, применяете `str_replace` - профит !

Answer (score 1):

Без регулярок:

```
$clubs = [
    'club1',
    '234534',
    'superlife',
    'club2',
];
$rep = 'club';
foreach ($clubs as $club) {
    if (false !== strpos($club, $rep)) {
        $club = str_replace($rep, '', $club);
    }
    echo $club;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа такого:

```
<?php

$clubs = [
    'club5353',
    '234534',
    'superlife',
    'club123456',
];

foreach ($clubs as $club) {
    var_dump(preg_replace("/^club(\d+)/", "$1", $club));
}
```

Вывод:

```
string(4) "5353"
string(6) "234534"
string(9) "superlife"
string(6) "123456"
```

обратите внимание, что слово club должно начинаться с начала строки, за это отвечает символ ^

Comment: Вы уверены, что не будет `cLuBtext124214` или просто `club` и ваша регулярка рухнет мертвым грузом, тут и обычными `strpos + str_replace` без труда справятся.

Comment: Да, уверен. Можете сами поэкспериментировать http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d7f7aab9c863ab25ae61eb07f0bb4e97aa7f1abf

Comment: @And это для вк, там слово клуб всегда впереди и сопровождается цифрами после, тобишь его ид. Можете привести ваш пример?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно оставить только числа *(т.е., удалить лишние элементы массива)*, то можно сперва отобрать необходимые строки, а потом отобрать числа:

```
$clubs = [
    'club5353',
    '234534',
    'superlife',
    'club123456',
];

$clubs = preg_replace('~\D+~', '', preg_grep('~^club\d+~', $clubs));

var_dump($clubs);
```

Результат:

```
array (
  0 => 5353
  3 => 123456
)
```